# Brownian motion semigroup is $C^{1,2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, brownian-motion

This is a problem from Rene Schilling's Brownian Motion.

Let $u \in B_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$, i.e. bounded Borel measurable map. And set 
$u(t,z):= P_t u(z)=p_t *u(z)=(2\pi t)^{-d/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} u(y)e^{-|z-y|^2 /2t} dy.$

Show that $u(t,\cdot) \in C^\infty$ and $u \in C^{1,2}$.

Solution is given below. In the proof to showing that $x \mapsto \partial_t u(t,x)$ is in $C^\infty$ for $t>0$, we need to find a uniform bound for $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{|z-y|^2}{t^2} - \frac{d}{t}) p_t(z-y)$ to use the domination argument. I am struggling to come up with a bound for this. I would appreciate some help here.

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific what you are struggling with? The reasoning works exactly as in the first part...

Comment: @saz My problem was that, to use the domination argument to get differentiability in $t$, we need to find a uniform bound $w(x) \in L^1(dx)$ for $\partial_t p_t(z-y) \le w(z)$,  for $t>0$, but $1/t^2$ and $1/t$ are unbounded.

Comment: "My problem **was** [...]" So you have already solved your problem?

Comment: @saz Sorry a misuse of word there. I still haven't figured this one out yet.

Comment: Hint: Consider $t \in [a,b] \subseteq (0,\infty)$ for some $0<a<b$.